# MS Access Form: Tuen Allow Edit to No and then apply filter using combo box

Tags: microsoft-access

Can anyone help me in Ms Access Split Form?

I have three fields Country,Product, and Year in Table Cap.
I have added Combobox in form for these field .
I want that if one combo box value is selected it should display related record below without allowing to edit record.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Perhaps a screenshot of your form, maybe code?

Comment: Hello @r0berts, there is a table Cap and it has three field Product,Country,Year .. i use form to Create split form , i didn't add any code in that , i just turn Form.AllowEdit property to False so that no one can edit the form. In the form a Combo box is added to select country but as the edit property is turn to false i cannot select any record. so i want to make the comobo box a filter by keeing the edit property of form to false. Thank you.

Comment: @r0berts, in split form there is combo box in the detail section of form and datasheet below.I want that through combo box user can search record from datasheet but they cannot edit the record in datasheet. Thank you.

Comment: I think I understand. Can you attach a screenshot to your question with the drop down selected as you would want it to work?

Comment: @r0berts, the combo box have values, when i select any value like Country to USA , it should  display related record in split datasheet below.

Comment: I understand. I would have done it making the data source of the tabular form a query where the filtering is done by referring to the corresponding parent form field. I would need to play around with this a bit too produce a working solution and earliest I could do that is tomorrow night. But you may have done it by yourself then.

Comment: @r0berts, i am trying this from many day but i am not able to , i really appreciate if you could do it at your earliest. Thank you.